# Javascript var inisde array

Tags: javascript

I want to use the value of a variable inside a array, like this.

```
 var advalue = Math.floor(Math.random * 6);
 var ads = ["Hello", "World", "Randomword", "123", "1233", "0000"];
 API.sendChat("Word: " + ads[advalue]);
```

When i run this, i get `undefined`

Comment: Fine, and where is the problem?

Comment: I return with an undefined.

Comment: `Math.random()` is a function, not a property.

Comment: Still the result is undefined wether i multiply it with 5 or 6.

Comment: Have a look at what `advalue` contains then? In this example, if it's anything other than 0-5 then it's not going to work.

Comment: This question is answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a typo, missing brackets after `random`

```
var advalue = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6);
```

Comment: Thank you, this worked i can't set this as an answer at the moment.